# What are the possible criminal sanctions for assault?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, assault

If an incident of assault is investigated by the police, what are the possible recourses that can be taken to sanction the individual in cases where the victim suffered no physical injuries?

Also, with video evidence available is there anything that may cause police to not investigate it? What would determine how much effort they would actually expend on investigating it? For example, knowing the appearance of the perpetrators though not their names, but knowing the name and address of the incorporated charity with which they're all associated.

Comment: These are at least 4 different questions. Please only pose one.

Comment: @TrishBut they are all closely related and in essence all different aspects of one same question.

Comment: @JosephP. "What are the possible criminal sanctions for assault?" is a question about the law and differs from the (imo unknowable) "what will police do in practice?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the possible criminal sanctions for assault?

For England and Wales, to answer such a question you could search for

assault site:sentencingcouncil.org.uk

which leads to https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/outlines/assault/

or

assault site:cps.gov.uk

which leads to https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/offences-against-person-incorporating-charging-standard

From the first link:

> Sentencing for assault depends on the offence type.
>
> Common assault:
>
> - the maximum sentence is six months’ custody
> - if the assault is against an emergency worker, the maximum sentence is one year’s custody
> - if the assault is racially or religiously aggravated, the maximum sentence is two years’ custody
>
> Actual bodily harm:
>
> - the maximum sentence is five years’ custody
> - if the assault is racially or religiously aggravated, the maximum sentence is seven years’ custody
>
> Grievous bodily harm or wounding:
>
> - the maximum sentence is five years’ custody.
> - if the assault is racially or religiously aggravated, the maximum sentence is seven years’ custody
> - if the assault was committed with intent to cause GBH/wounding then the maximum sentence is life imprisonment

Comment: And which one of the above would apply to someone who received no injury as a result of the other person's actions? ([hint, hint](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/news/item/assault-offences-explained/_))

Comment: @Richard your link is 404 - I don't know if that's deliberate. "Threatening words or a raised fist is enough for the crime [of common assault] to have been committed" - Sentencing Council page linked in my answer

Comment: Oops; https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/news/item/assault-offences-explained/